# How to install specific clang version on OSX?

Tags: macos, clang, homebrew, travis-ci

I need to have a specific clang version 3.9 for Travis CI for OSX. None of the following approaches has worked so far:

**Approach 1:** This doesn't work because it doesn't get specific version. Plus it takes huge amount of time exceeding Travis CI's 10 minutes.

```
brew install llvm
```

**Approach 2:** This does gets specific version but doesn't work because it takes huge amount of time exceeding Travis CI's 10 minutes.

```
brew install llvm@3.9
```

**Approach 3:** Below was supposedly installing binaries and hence faster but its now deprecated and erroring out:

```
brew install homebrew/versions/llvm39
```

I'm just looking for the OSX equivalent of `sudo apt-get install -y clang-3.9 clang++-3.9` which is fast and works on Linux pretty well.

Comment: After installing llvm have you check the dir `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin` ?

Comment: Seems you have explored many homebrew solutions for your problem. Given that, what I would do would be to use directly the official download page and:  
`time curl -# -o clang3_9_0.tar.xz http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/clang+llvm-3.9.0-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz`   
`tar -xJf clang3_9_0.tar.xz` .  
Then this will have your bin, include, lib and libexec dirs. You can put this dirs in env variable, or just the just extracted clang llvm folder and use this to access /bin, /include, /lib...

Comment: Does it need to be the pure clang version, or would a cross-referenced XCode version suffice? Travis-CI provides images for older XCode versions.  https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/objective-c/

Answer (score 0):

There are only certain versions that you can install using brew that you can list them using this command:

```
brew search llvm
==> Formulae
llvm                    llvm@6                  llvm@7 
llvm@8                  llvm@9
```

You can see all of the llvm and clang versions in this address:
https://releases.llvm.org/download.html

you can build them following this instruction: http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

For my case I only wanted clang4 so I got it from: 
https://github.com/rmacoslib/r-macos-clang